# Using iText, how can I apply css to my PDF document using CssResolver and CssFile?

Tags: java, itext

Thanks for your help...

## Problem

While converting an html table tag/snippet (which I have converted to string) into a PDF document...

I am able to **successfully**  apply css styles to the PDF document using this technique...

```
CSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(false);  
cssResolver.addCss("td {border-right: white .1px solid;}", true);
```

But, I am **unsuccessful** applying css to the PDF document using existing a css file (i.e., using CssFile object),  like this...

```
CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
InputStream csspathtest = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("styles/itextweb.css");            
CssFile cssfiletest = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(csspathtest);
cssResolver.addCss(cssfiletest);
```

...I have not been able to get this working, and dont know what the issue is...I'm getting...

```
Java.io.IOException The document has no pages
```

## Question:

How do I properly use CssFile with CssResolver to apply css styles -- i.e., from existing ".css" files -- to my PDF document?   (What is wrong with the way I am using iText to accomplish this?)

(Again, thank you for any help/guidance on this)

================= BELOW IS MORE DETAILED INFOMATION ===================

Java 6, JSF (Mojarra) 2.1.11, Primefaces v3.4.2, itextpdf v5.3.4, xmlworker v1.2.1

## This is the "printPDF" function in question...

```
public void createPDF() throws DocumentException, CssResolverException
{
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext econtext = context.getExternalContext();

    try
    {
        String htmlstring   = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("testForm:htmlstring");

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlstring.getBytes());             
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 

        // step 1
        Document document = new Document();

        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);

        writer.setInitialLeading(12.5f);

        // step 3
        document.open();

        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);

        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

        // CSS
        CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
        InputStream csspathtest = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("styles/itextweb.css");            
        CssFile cssfiletest = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(csspathtest);
        cssResolver.addCss(cssfiletest);             

        Pipeline<?> pipeline =  new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer)));

        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
        XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
        p.parse(is); //new FileInputStream("results/demo2/walden.html"));

        // step     
        document.close();

        //post back...
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");           
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment;filename=file.pdf");
        response.setContentLength(baos.size());
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        baos.writeTo(os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        context.responseComplete();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (DocumentException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

## This is the page containing the html table snippet to be parsed to pdf (i.e., id="table1")...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <title>test html-to-pdf with itext...</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <h:form id="testForm">

                <p:panel id="queryPanel"  header="...test itext html-to-pdf conversion..." style="width:100%;">

                    <table id='table1'>
                        <thead class="dt-thd">
                            <tr id="table1-h-hdr-row">
                                <th style="width: 120px" class="dt-hhdr-c " >Last name</th>
                                <th style="width: 120px" class="dt-hhdr-c " >First Name</th>
                                <th style="width: 120px" class="dt-hhdr-c " >Middle Name</th>
                                <th style="width: 180px" class="dt-hhdr-c " >Date Of Birth</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="dt-r-even" onclick="uiOnRowClick('table1', 14, this)">
                                <td style="width: 120px" class="dt-c  row-selected-left" ><a class="column-link " onfocus="uiOnRowClick('table1', 14, this.parentNode.parentNode)" onclick="storeFilters()" href="#">lastnameAAA</a></td>
                                <td style="width: 120px" class="dt-c  row-selected" >firstnameAAA</td>
                                <td style="width: 120px" class="dt-c  row-selected" >A</td>
                                <td style="width: 180px" class="dt-c  row-selected" >11/27/1971</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="dt-r-odd" onclick="uiOnRowClick('table1', 14, this)">
                                <td style="width: 120px" class="dt-c " ><a class="column-link " onfocus="uiOnRowClick('table1', 14, this.parentNode.parentNode)" onclick="storeFilters()" href="#">lastnameBBB</a></td>
                                <td style="width: 120px" class="dt-c " >firstnameBBB</td>
                                <td style="width: 120px" class="dt-c " >B</td>
                                <td style="width: 180px" class="dt-c " >01/15/1951</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="dt-r-even" onclick="uiOnRowClick('table1', 14, this)">
                                <td style="width: 120px" class="dt-c " ><a class="column-link " onfocus="uiOnRowClick('table1', 14, this.parentNode.parentNode)" onclick="storeFilters()" href="#">lastnameCCC</a></td>
                                <td style="width: 120px" class="dt-c " >firstnameCCC</td>
                                <td style="width: 120px" class="dt-c " >C</td>
                                <td style="width: 180px" class="dt-c " >02/16/1962</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="dt-r-odd" onclick="uiOnRowClick('table1', 14, this)">
                                <td style="width: 120px" class="dt-c " ><a class="column-link " onfocus="uiOnRowClick('table1', 14, this.parentNode.parentNode)" onclick="storeFilters()" href="#">lastnameDDD</a></td>
                                <td style="width: 120px" class="dt-c " >firstnameDDD</td>
                                <td style="width: 120px" class="dt-c " >D</td>
                                <td style="width: 180px" class="dt-c " >03/17/1973</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="dt-r-even" onclick="uiOnRowClick('table1', 14, this)">
                                <td style="width: 120px" class="dt-c " ><a class="column-link " onfocus="uiOnRowClick('table1', 14, this.parentNode.parentNode)" onclick="storeFilters()" href="#">lastnameEEE</a></td>
                                <td style="width: 120px" class="dt-c " >firstnameEEE</td>
                                <td style="width: 120px" class="dt-c " >E</td>
                                <td style="width: 180px" class="dt-c " >04/18/1984</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="dt-r-odd" onclick="uiOnRowClick('table1', 14, this)">
                                <td style="width: 120px" class="dt-c " ><a class="column-link " onfocus="uiOnRowClick('table1', 14, this.parentNode.parentNode)" onclick="storeFilters()" href="#">lastnameFFF</a></td>
                                <td style="width: 120px" class="dt-c " >firstnameFFF</td>
                                <td style="width: 120px" class="dt-c " >F</td>
                                <td style="width: 180px" class="dt-c " >05/19/1995</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <p:commandButton
                        id="printPdf"
                        value="Print"
                        action="#{testBean.createPDF2}"
                        ajax="false"
                        onclick="printPreview(this);this.form.target='_blank'"/>

                    <h:inputHidden id="htmlstring" value="no value"/>

                </p:panel>

            </h:form>

            <h:outputStylesheet  library="styles"    name="itextweb.css"      />
            <h:outputScript      library="primefaces" name="/jquery/jquery.js" />
            <h:outputScript      library="primefaces" name="/jquery/plugins/ui/jquery-ui.custom.js" />
            <h:outputScript      library="primefaces" name="/jquery/plugins/inputmask/maskedinput.js" />
            <h:outputScript      library="js"         name="itextweb.js" />
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

## Here is the javascript used...

```
function uiOnRowClick(a, b, c)
{
    alert("uiOnRowClick(a,b,c) function called...blah...");
}

function storeFilters()
{
    alert("storeFilters() function called...bleah...");
}

function printPreview(e)
{
    var t = document.getElementById("table1");
    var htmlstring = "<table id='table1-hdr' class='dt' style='width:2416px;position:absolute'>" + t.innerHTML + "</table>";
    document.getElementById('testForm:htmlstring').value = htmlstring;
}
```

## Here is the CSS stylesheet for this example...

```
.text1
{
    background-color: transparent !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: blue;
    text-align:center;
}

.ui-inputfield {
    background: white !important;
    height: 10px !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


.ui-button
{
    margin-top: .5px !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    display:inline-block !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}

.ui-message-error
{
    background: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
    font-size: .9em !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;
}

.ui-message-error-icon {
    display: none;
}

.ui-messages-error
{
    background: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
    font-size: .9em !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;
}

.ui-messages-error-icon {
    display: none;
}

.ui-inputfield.ui-state-error
{
    background: pink !important;
}

form *
{
box-sizing: content-box !important;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
-ms-box-sizing: content-box !important;
}


.ui-widget, .ui-widget .ui-widget
{
font-size: 90% !important;
}


.dt-thd
{

}

.table1-h-hdr-row
{

}

.dt-hhdr-c
{
    color: blue;
    background-color:  lightgray;
}

.dt-r-odd
{
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

.dt-r-even
{
    background-color:  lightskyblue;
}

.dt-c
{
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

## Below is the pom.xml used with this example (which illustrates dependenies/versions/etc)...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextweb-war</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1</version>
    <name>itextweb-war</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>aristo</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This question is not related with JSF. Maybe you use JSF in your web app, but this question is outside the JSF scope.

Comment: *I have not been able to get this working, and dont know what the issue is*. Does this mean that you haven't debugged your code? Did you at least get a value in the `cssfiletest` or a `null` (which indicates that the file couldn't be found)?

Comment: Hi Luiggi- have you gotten the CssFile/CssResolver technique to work yourself, by chance?  If so, are you able to see any obvious issues w/ the code snippits I've provided?  Thx for your help.

Comment: I haven't worked with those components, but as far as it looks the only problem might be that your `InputStream csspathtest` doesn't contain your right CSS file.

Comment: Hi Luiggi - you were right... the IS object was null, so I adjusted the path URL and now its no longer null... However, now when the PDF document object is closed, I'm getting:   "java.io.IOException: The document has no pages."  My guess is that this is symptomatic of something else...but, its not clear what...  Stuck again...

Comment: It looks that your error is that the `InputStream` isn't closed after using it (very strange). You can try moving to the latest version of iText (crossing your fingers and hoping that this problem is solved) or check where the problem occurs and *try to close the stream by yourself*. As I've told you before, I haven't worked with these classes/methods but you can do some experiments. When you have an answer, please post it and explain how to deal with this problem in order to help peoplein the future :).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try.  Maybe we'll get lucky and someone else will read the post and offer an answer(or hint).  Fwiw, I wondering whether I needed to convert the cssfiletest object so hat I might try using the "cssResolver.addCssFile" (I think that's the name of it) instead.  Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Created a project starting from your code, tested and it works very well to create a PDF file from a html file with external CSS.

Here is the public repository: https://github.com/valentin-nasta/itext-html-css-pdf-jsf-template .

Comment: Hi Valentin - can you also successfully convert the HTML table itself to PDF (I added more code detail to the original post)?  I am actually posting the table (and its contents) as a string to the backing bean/controller.  I dont want to parse the entire html page, etc.  I tried adapting your solution to convert the aforementioned table string, but, I still receive the same error...~document contains no pages, etc.  What do you think?  BTW - Thanks very much for attending to my posted issue.

Comment: I did some research and seams that xmlworker support just some of the CSS styles. Here you have [supported css styles](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm) . Made some small tests with basic styles like `table {
 color: red;
 background-color: blue;
}` and it's working.

Comment: Also found the problem. Try with `lightgrey` instead of `lightgray` for background-color on class `.dt-hhdr-c` , on my side it works this way. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, Valentin ... I will give this a try and get back to you

Comment: Thanks Valentin ...  The issue does appear to be related to unsupported CSS styles.  Ironically, though you've answered my question, it appears I will not be able to implement the CSS "file" solution - due to this limitation. Thanks for your research/answer.

Comment: What about the class support?

Answer (score 2):

I think a better and more powerful (and higher level of abstraction) tool for this purpose (generating PDF files from XHTML) would be Flying Saucer, aka. xhmlrenderer.

It gives complete CSS2 support and a few CSS3 properties for print media, and you can extend it to render any PDF's (see the ReplacementElementFactory API).

I've used it to render dynamic PDF reports (with freemarker), with custom tags, like . Very simple tool and easy to understand.

See: http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/

The user guide can be found here: http://flyingsaucerproject.github.com/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html

Comment: Thanks, Persics.  Unfortunately I am not permitted to use the Flying Saucer software.

Answer (score 2):

nope flying saucer is out of lifetime not supported anymore. we having lots of trouble with it. for private use its ok, but not in a business case.

Comment: This is not an answer, it should have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

For cssResolver you need to specify the absoulte path for the .css as shown below.

```
HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);

htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

CSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(false);

cssResolver.addCssFile("src\\template\\style.css",true);
Pipeline<?> pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer)));

XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser(worker);
```