# How to add css external file to iText?

Tags: java, itext

Im using iText v2.0.8 and I've got html with  to my external css files. Is it possible to load these styles to iText?

Comment: Did you see this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783231/using-itext-how-can-i-apply-css-to-my-pdf-document-using-cssresolver-and-cssfil

Comment: iText 2 can't deal with external CSS files, you need [XML worker](http://itextpdf.com/product/xml_worker). There are many XML Worker examples (including examples involving external CSS) in the [sandbox](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker). This is also a possible duplicate of [How to convert HTML to PDF using iTextSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp)